# Do repositories for mesos available on xenial?

Tags: repository, mesos, marathon, mesosphere

I am not able to install mesos and marathon on ubuntu 16.04. I have added the official repository provided by mesosphere. Do repositories available for mesos on xenial?

Following my distributions details.

```
root@sandipd-ThinkPad-E450:~# lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial
root@sandipd-ThinkPad-E450:~#
```

Trying to install but it gives following error.

```
root@sandipd-ThinkPad-E450:~# apt-get install mesosphere
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package mesosphere
```

I have added following repositories from mesosphere website.

```
echo "deb http://repos.mesosphere.com/${DISTRO} ${CODENAME} main" | 
sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mesosphere.list
```

Comment: I guess I need to install these packages separately with this command: apt-get install mesos and marathon not with the meta package apt-get install mesosphere.  Using meta package its not working.

Answer (score 0):

Use apt-get install mesos marathon. Dont use meta packages mesosphere. Thanks.